# C# Wpf MVVM Make XamRibbon Tabs dependent on selected objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Currently, I possess a List of Objects in my Model, which contains all selected items from the View.

```
private List<Object> _objectList;

    public List<Object> ObjectList
    {
        get { return _objectList; }
        set { _objectList = value; }
    }
```

My view contains a XamRibbon, which I would like to add ContextualTabs to, depending on the selected objects (Much like in Office Word, when you select a table, a specifically created contextual tab for formatting shows up).

The problem is, that those Objects can differ in type (TextBox, Button, custom objects, etc.). What would be the best approach to figure out which contextual tab to show and how would I do it?

Disregarding MVVM, it could look like this:

```
public void ManageItem(XamRibbon myRibbon, string objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == "TextBox")
        {
            ManageTextBoxItems(myRibbon);
        }
        else if (objectType == "CheckBox")
        {
            ManageCheckBoxItems(myRibbon);
        }
    }
```

ManageCheckBoxItems() would then create a ContextualTabGroup and add certain elements from code-behind.

The objectType could be received like this:

```
private string GetObjectType()
    {
        string objectType = "";

        if (Keyboard.FocusedElement != null)
        {
            objectType = Keyboard.FocusedElement.GetType().Name;
        }
        return objectType;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this would violate the MVVM principles, so I have been looking for a different way to do this, although unsuccessfully. Additionally, this wouldn't be nicely designed code.

I hoped for an idea, which could lead me onto the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just have a `ContentControl` in your ribbon whose Content is bound to a `RibbonContextVM` property on your main VM.

`RibbonContextVM` gets set to an appropriate VM type (eg `CheckBoxContextVM`) when the context changes, and the `ContentControl` displays an appropriate view using the usual `DataTemplate` mappings.

The VM can be informed of context changes via a `ContextChangedCommand` which is called from code behind in the view in response to focus changes. It can take a string / type / enum / whatever as its command parameter.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan! But how would I set the RibbonContextVM's type to an appropriate one in practice?

Comment: Probably just a simple switch statement that new's up the appropriate type based on ContextChangedCommand param?

Comment: Alright. I'll try my best. Thank you for your help :)